# Simple footer troubles

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a footer for my page and I'm using the following CSS:

```
#footer {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The footer appears at the bottom of the page as it should. I can see the text I write glued to the bottom of the page properly. However, the background colors refuse to appear at all. It's just the plain white background of the rest of the page.

Any idea why this is happening?

**EDIT** Checked for any conflicting/overriding CSS. Nothing that I can see.

**EDIT2** The HTML

```
<div id="footer">
    <center><p> Sup dawg, I'm a footer </p></center>    
</div>
```

Comment: I made a fiddle with the updated css & html http://jsfiddle.net/xvqhf/1/, seems to be working try running your html through a validator http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input also, are you using firebug?  Also try removing all of your css except for the footer styling, if it works then add your css back into the page in small increments until the markup quits working, using a binary approach will speed this process up

Comment: `center`, is depreciated.  What happens when you remove that tag?

Comment: @kmb385 There is a LOT of CSS on the page... I'm a little hesitant to remove some of it. Would an overriding `background-color` be the problem? Is there anything specifically I should be looking for?

Comment: @George Understood. Tried removing it, didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: @Tory I suspect a css conflict.  Don't hesitate to remove the css, just make a backup of the file beforehand you can always revert back  to the backup.  If its not css, its most likely an open tag aka invalid html.  BTW what browser are you using?  These situations make Firefox and Firebug a developers best friend.

Comment: Your HTML/CSS for `#footer` couldn't be more simple.  Obviously something else is over-riding it but without seeing more HTML, CSS, or a live page, I'm not sure how you're going to get very much help here.  I will not post answers below that are merely guesses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The css attribute to set the background color is background color.  Change your css to:

```
#footer {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gfKXU/1/

Comment: I changed that, background still doesn't appear.

Comment: @Tory Is the footer getting the other styles applied such as the height and position?

Comment: Yes, the position I know is at least getting applied. The footer appears at the wayyyy bottom of the page. My HTML is posted... the CSS contains stylings for quite a few pages and would only cause confusion.

Comment: yep, it was being overwritten by another tag

Comment: @Tory Waterman:  For the sake and benefit of future readers, I'm hoping you could edit your OP to include the specific code that caused your issue.  Thank-you!

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean `background-color: #F3F3F3;` instead?

Comment: Changed that, still doesnt appear.

Comment: @Tory Have you tried setting a width?  Could be a quirk to your browser.

Comment: @Tory Perhaps you could post your markup where you use this style?